# Java Datatypes - Hacker Rank

Tags: java, types

I am trying to solve a problem on hacker rank so what I have to do is listed [here](http://hackerrank.com/challenges/java-datatypes/problem) (explanation of the code), and I have managed to make the code run and work, but it fails 2 of the tests.[image]

here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaDatatypes {
    public static void main(String[] argh) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            try {
                long x = sc.nextLong();
                System.out.println(x + " can be fitted in:");

                int[] bits = {8, 16, 32, 64};
                String[] strings = {"byte", "short", "int", "long"};
                for (int j = 0; j < bits.length; j++) {
                    long range = (long) (Math.pow(2, bits[j] - 1));
                    if (x >= -range && x <= range -1) {
                        System.out.println("* " + strings[j]);
                    }
                }
                //Complete the code
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(sc.next() + " can't be fitted anywhere.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at the expected output and it expects `9223372036854775807` to be outputed as a long, and my code isn't outputting that as a long I am not sure why.

Comment: What is the actual output? What are you trying to do with your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @dan1st https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-datatypes/problem

Comment: Because you didn't include the actual output, the input (you pnly included the input of one test case) and what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @dan1st I only included input that was wrong. we didn't need any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in you code is that you use `double pow(double a, double b)`. When you have result closer to `Long.MAX_VALUE` - the result is **rounded**. You can check it by `BitInteger`:

```
String str1 = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(bits[j] - 1).toString();
String str2 = String.valueOf((long)Math.pow(2, bits[j] - 1));
```

These strings should be equal every time, but for `2^16` - it's not. That's why for `2^16` your `x <= range - 1` is not correct.

---

You do not need to use `for loop` to check this. Java has constants like `Byte.MIN_VALUE`, `Byte.MAX_VALUE`.

```
public static void main(String[] argh) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {

        try {
            long x = sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(x + " can be fitted in:");
            if (x >= Byte.MIN_VALUE && x <= Byte.MAX_VALUE)
                System.out.println("* byte");
            if (x >= Short.MIN_VALUE && x <= Short.MAX_VALUE)
                System.out.println("* short");
            if (x >= Integer.MIN_VALUE && x <= Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                System.out.println("* int");
            System.out.println("* long");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(sc.next() + " can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would rather do it my way, I am just trying to find the problem in my code.

Comment: @SamHoque Added comment

Comment: Using BigInterger fixed it, weird that math.pow wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just omit the check for 64 bits and `long`.

If `long x = sc.nextLong();` succeeds without exception, you already know that the number fits into the `long` type. So, you can always print "* long" if you didn't get an exception.

One remark on using `Math.pow()`: it's based on floating-point arithmetic and as such, it might involve small rounding errors. Powers of 2 can be computed by bit-shifting, so

```
long range = (long) (Math.pow(2, bits[j] - 1))
```

can be replaced by

```
long range = 2L << (bits[j] - 1)
```

This gives exact results and also is faster than `Math.pow()`.

Comment: Returns Operator '<<' cannot be applied to 'long', 'double'

Comment: There's no `double` in `2L << (bits[j] - 1)`.